# Upload Single file with create and modify dates

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

When uploading single file into one drive for business I can't find a way to add a create and modify date.
when I use resumeable upload for file more then 4 Mb it is working but not for single small files.

using the Microsoft graph .NET SDK

```
var client = await GetGraphClient(request);
var stream = new FileStream(request.LocalPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

client.Me.Drive.Root.ItemWithPath($"{ds.FolderPath}/{request.File.Name}").Content.Request().PutAsync<DriveItem>(stream);
```

how do I upload with this method a file with create and modify date??

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no way to do this in a single request with OneDrive Business - you'll have to follow the put-to-content request with a metadata update that includes the timestamps.

In the future the goal is to align with OneDrive Personal and allow multipart requests that include both the metadata and the file content, but this is not yet available.

Comment: OK thanks that is exactly what i am doing  but, When i doing a requst for the update i am getting an exception :

Comment: Are you updating `fileSystemInfo.createdDateTime` and `fileSystemInfo.lastModifiedDateTime` or are you trying to update the ones directly on the item? Only the two I mentioned in this comment can be updated.